# Can I use pinch to zoom in evince?

Tags: pdf, multi-touch, evince

I have a touch screen device running ubuntu.
When viewing pdfs in evince I can use one finger scrolling and it's very fluent and satisfying.

I am looking for more support for touch gestures. 
Specifically, looking at [these patch notes](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/3.6.1-1ubuntu1) and a quick google would suggest that evince should supports pinch to zoom, however it doesn't seem to work for me.
Is there some flag or command I need to make evince understand pinch to zoom.

Can I activate this feature somehow?

Additional information:

```
$ evince --version
GNOME Document Viewer 3.10.3

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Update:

According to the gnome source it looks like evince will support pinch gestures in version [3.13.90](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/evince/3.13/evince-3.13.90.changes).

Comment: what version of evince & ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Sorry I should have said. evince --version gives "GNOME Document Viewer 3.10.3" and I'm running ubuntu 14.04